# How can a buffer around a point not be a circle? (Or, strange behavior of rgeos::gBuffer() )

Tags: r, r-sp, r-sf

I've switched from package `sp` to `sf` for many of my geo-things in `R`, and only now I noticed a strange behavior in `sp`/`rgeos`. Here it is:

```
library(sp)
library(sf)
library(rgeos)

# crs
WGS84M = "+proj=merc +lon_0=0 +k=1 +x_0=0 +y_0=0 +datum=WGS84 +units=m +no_defs"

# a point
point = data.frame(x = 0, y = 0)

# simple feature from point
f.point = st_as_sf(point, coords = c('x', 'y'))
st_crs(f.point) = WGS84M
f.buf = st_geometry(st_buffer(f.point, dist = 5 * 1000))

# spatial object from point
s.point = SpatialPoints(point, proj4string = CRS(WGS84M))
s.buf = gBuffer(s.point, width = 5 * 1000)

plot(s.buf, border = "blue")
plot(f.buf, border = "red", add = T)
```

I get this:

[image]

Perhaps the resolution of the image I uploaded isn't great, but the point here is: there's a circle in red, and a non-circle (I tried to count the sides, seems to be a 20-gon) in blue. If you convert the `sf` object to `sp` you still get a circle, and if you convert the `sp` object to `sf`, you still get a 20-gon (so it isn't just a difference, say, in plot methods).

I expected `gBuffer()` around a point to return a circle. Is there a reason I shouldn't expect that? Can anyone explain what's going on?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fine [rgeos::gBuffer documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgeos/versions/0.5-2/topics/gBuffer) includes

> **quadsegs** [default=5] Number of line segments to use to approximate a quarter circle.

thus a 20-gon (=4*5) is exactly what you should expect with the default settings.  If you want something closer to a circle, increase the value of `quadsegs`.

I assume this is done for computational efficiency.

Comment: An important point is that the red shape isn't a circle either - its a 120-agon, because `?st_buffer` has `nQuadSegs = 30`. If you want a perfect Platonic circle in R you'll need to represent it as an object with a centre and a radius.

Comment: @djas `c1 = list(radius=4.3, centre=c(2.2, 5.12))` or similar. I don't know if there's an R package to work with explicit exact geometric objects. Go check CRAN for one.